# checked box value has usually the value of No in sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepint

I check my checkbox in the Form and i save it! but in the sharepoint list i find that the value is usual No! when i don't check it it's empty in the list.

I want if i check i find yes if not i find No.

this is my code :

```
function Save() 
{
    var Regulated = $('input[name=Regulated]:checked').val();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("PendingList");
    var item = oList.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
    item.set_item('Regulated', Regulated);
    item.update();  
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded_SaveTo),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed_SaveTo)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input[name=Regulated]').is(':checked')` will give you a proper boolean value whereas `$('input[name=Regulated]:checked').val()` returns 'on' when checked and `undefined` when unchecked. Try the updated code below:

```
function Save() {
    var Regulated = $('input[name=Regulated]').is(':checked');
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("PendingList");
    var item = oList.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
    item.set_item('Regulated', Regulated);
    item.update();  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded_SaveTo),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed_SaveTo)
    );
}
```